# Создание исполняемого файла .exe при помощи Apache Cordova для платформы Windows XP/7/8/10

Tags: windows, visual-studio, node.js, exe, cordova

Официальная документация Apache Cordova описывает создание Windows приложения, существует ли возможность представить его в виде исполняемого файла .exe, .bat или .msi ?

Answer (score 1):

В [VisualStudioCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) есть такая фишка, там надо поставить поддержку Cordova и потом можно собирать приложения, так же можно собирать вручную ,но не очень удобно. к стати есть ещё AppJS  и Node-WEBKit . они решают по сути те-же задачи, к стати вроде как Cordova под XP работает не очень

Comment: сборка Visual в каком виде? appx? Про Node-WEBKit знаю только что это отдельный инструмент сборки, по сути chromium на базе V8, может как альтернатива, но вес большой, порядка 100мб

Comment: про сборку в Code не скажу. лучше почитать например тут - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771545.aspx , когда ставил Code на "поиграться" то там ставил отдельно кордову, но она меня не впечатлило , по сути XP в пролёте, как я понял она работает по сути через ядро IE, а там js мягко говоря кастрированный, так что даже не стал с ним заморачиваться , Node-WEBKit выглядит интереснее но там экзешник от 50мб, ещё у Qt есть подобная технология, но особо не изучал, пока решил остатся на node.js

Answer (score 0):

Cordova позволяет собирать только Metro/Windows Store/WinJS приложения, т.е. плиточные приложения для ОС Windows 8.0 и выше.